# First loop is breaking in between and not going all the way

Tags: excel, vba

Code is not inserting columns until it finds all columns in range, where as it stopping when it reaches on 22nd column even though I have another 6 columns available, if I specify a digit 40 in place of NewColsone here for code `For coly = 6 To 40 Step 4` it works

```
Sub LatestCRDThree()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("New CRD.xlsm")
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("A.xlsx")
    With wb.Worksheets("B")
        NewColsone = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
    End With

    With wb.Worksheets("B")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        For coly = 6 To NewColsone Step 4 ' starting from 6th column enter a new column after consecutive 3 columns
            NewColsone = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
            Columns(coly).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            NewColsone = NewColsone + 1
            Next coly
        End With
        For j = 6 To NewColsone Step 4
            If wb.Worksheets("B").Cells(2, j).Value = "" Then
                wb1.Worksheets("Required_Values").Range("A1").Copy Destination:=wb.Worksheets("B").Cells(2, j)
                wb1.Worksheets("Required_Values").Range("A5").Copy Destination:=wb.Worksheets("B").Cells(1, j)
            End If
            Next j
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    coly = 6
    While NewColsone > coly
        Columns(Coly).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        NewColsone = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        coly = coly + 4
    Wend
```

instead of

```
For coly = 6 To NewColsone Step 4 ' starting from 6th column enter a new column after consecutive 3 columns
    NewColsone = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Columns(coly).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    NewColsone = NewColsone + 1
Next coly
```